# Upcoming change in moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

As some have noticed, recently I haven't been able to spend as much time on AI.SE as I did earlier in the site's life. A lot has changed since then; our site specifically has grown and improved a lot. Originally I offered my services as an experienced user of the Stack Exchange network, but now that we are an established site it is much more desirable to have moderators with more subject matter experience.

I therefore believe it's time for a more active and knowledgeable contributor to take my place. A month ago, I notified the other two moderators of my intention to step down. I submitted the official notice to Stack Exchange on October 11 and will retire from moderation on November 12.

Some exciting news has come from this: a moderator election is being planned for AI.SE! Scheduling and details aren't nailed down yet, but it would likely begin some time in January 2020.

In the meantime, I am certain that the fantastic community and remaining moderators will be able to keep the site functioning smoothly. It has been a pleasure and honor to serve as moderator pro tempore, and I wish you all the best!

Comment: Heartfelt thanks for all the time and attention you gave the Stack.  You will be missed!