# January 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, elections

This community last had moderators appointed in 2017, so it's been a while...  In addition to that, you may have noticed that [one of the current mods — Ben N — is stepping down from their moderator position](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1601/45).

Since moderators were last appointed in this community, we've started and "graduated" an experiment: and pro-tem moderators [are now elected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332180/208518), just like "regular" moderators. As such, to find a replacement for Ben, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in January 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in January '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 7):

I am happy to run, especially if there is a shortage of candidates, although I think I am not the best candidate for the job.

Comment: You'd make an excellent mod John, even if you had less time to devote than you'd like.  Your background, expertise and judgement make you eminently qualified, and your participation on the mod team would be hugely beneficial to the stack.  (For any unfamiliar with John, I urge them to look at both his excellent answers and comments.)

Comment: I should probably also note that **John has degrees in mathematics & AI and a PhD in Computer Science/AI.  He has taught for several years at the college level, and now works in the private sector in an analytics company.**  In my considered opinion, this makes him an ideal candidate to moderate this forum.

Comment: (John, let me know if I got anything wrong--I think the information is relevant!)

Comment: @DukeZhou that is more or less correct. Both of my graduate degrees are in computer science (think of the MMath in CS as being like an MA in, say, Philosophy). Both of them specialized in AI. Thanks for the endorsement.

Answer (score 6):

I'm interested in running for a moderator position.

Comment: I'll note that **nbro led the drive to get math formatting on the stack**, which allowed us to blossom, doing all of the initial work to make it happen.  He spend a huge amount of time on the stack facilitating others by seeking clarifications, cleaning up questions & tags, and strictly adheres to the "be nice" policy. Also notable that he has the second greatest amount of rep, and that was attained in a relatively short time-frame, so I feel it's fair to say he has his finger on the pulse, and a clear vision of what we need to do to continue to improve.

Answer (score 3):

I would be interested in running. Though, I must say that the first two members that came to mind as the top candidates have already stated that they are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for writing to us about this. This isn’t our final response here, but in the interest of being transparent and keeping lines of communication open,***I myself, have been yearning for this mod - position for a long period of time.***
Therefore, with all my interest and the inner driving force, I'm running for this! I should even be hesitated for it.

Thanks once again for being informed. Keep us posted of any updates.

Comment: Why were you "yearning" for the position for a long time?