# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, elections

**Summary**: Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 17, 2020** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 17, 2020, users can [nominate themselves](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On February 24, 2020, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on March 3, 2020.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

---

> **Note:** The election date was pushed back a month, due to some ongoing back-end work on the election mechanics, in order to automate some steps.

Comment: Is there a plan for what to do if there are no candidates? After the recent tumultuous events on MSE I'd almost be surprised if it didn't happen somewhere on the network.

Comment: If there are no candidates, we'll extend the nomination period for one week, and cancel the election if that's not enough — our usual process. Though, [it seems there are users interested in running](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1602/45) :)

Comment: Why are we waiting for so long though?

Comment: Because of the holidays that are coming up, @DuttaA :)