# Are you interested in moderating Artificial Intelligence Stack exchange?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Our main site has [four moderators](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). Some ([nbro♦](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/2444/nbro)) are/is active and some are rarely active due to various reasons.

If there is a possibility in increasing the number of moderators, are you interested in becoming a moderator to our main site?

Comment: There's one moderator that rarely visits the site (although in the past he was very active for several months and he can really be useful when it comes to giving advice, as he's more experienced than me), but there's another one that regularly visits the site (and helps me when I ask explicitly him for help) and another that occasionally also does it (and, in the past, he used to help me a lot more).

Comment: It would be better if we had 4 really active moderators, but it's more important that we have active regular users, like you, that _regularly raise flags, ask for clarifications under the post, edit posts, ask and answer questions, etc._ Right now, you're doing a good job, and I really appreciate the work you've been doing.

Comment: Anyway, [it's usually a super-mod or mod that asks this question to the community](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1602/2444), but I am also interested to know if anyone is interested in this role.

Comment: Thanks @nbro I will try to preserve it.

Comment: What we really need is greater voting participation to better validate answers.  This stack improved enormously when nbro and Dennis joined the mod team, by bringing more clarity and focus, which renewed our energy.  I don't even remember when I became a mod on this stack, but it was sometime around AlphaGo, if I recall correctly.  I still consider myself a beginner in AI!  (But I'm glad we continue to attract both experts and serious students applying themselves rigorously.) I tend to see this as a project of decades.  This stack had almost no utility at the outset. Today it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am ambiguous about it and almost completely biased towards not becoming a moderator now.

**Reasons**:

I am a beginner in AI and hence I don't know much of the concepts in Artificial Intelligence. I may get confusions easily in editing or other tasks.

Along with less expertise in AI, I feel that my style of framing sentences may not be correctly interpret-able to many users on our main site.

But, I want to continue my contribution in some or other way as a member of or community rather than a moderator which needs some skills that currently I don't have.

Comment: I don't think being a moderator on a site should require you to be one of the high-ranking experts. In fact I think there's a clash in terms of time spent (do you want to answer questions, or contribute other things to the site?), and also possible conflicts of interest that you need to navigate. Instead I think you should consider your site reputation, which is a measure of how much the community thinks you contribute to the routine issues on the site. It means you are already trusted with a lot of the content as a regular user. The other issues you claim impact you are salient though, IMO.

Comment: @NeilSlater **The reputation is not always a good indication of how much we should trust a user**.  In the past, we had several users that got a lot of reputation, but they couldn't really be trusted. You probably remember them. Moreover, we often see people with 150k reputation being suspended or doing other bad things. So, I think that reputation is necessary to some little extent, but it's really not the most important thing to become a mod. You can have 500 rep and be a good mod, as long as you've shown, in other ways, that you cared for this community during the years.

Comment: @NeilSlater Having said that, I agree that you don't necessarily need to be an expert in all AI topics to be a mod (e.g. if you're an expert in RL but you don't know anything about expert systems, ok, fine), but I think it's important to have a good overall knowledge of the field or be interested in all aspects of AI, because, in certain situations, you also need to take certain decisions that would require knowledge of AI.